# Call focus() after jQuery append() is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `append()` and a `focus()` which is set to focus the first input in the appended `dom`.

IE is taking time to append and so the focus is not working. Is there a way (other than `setTimeout`) to set the focus after the `dom` is fully appended?

Thanks!

Comment: Post the code my friend.

Answer (score 1):

`append()` and `appendTo()` are synchronous commands so there is no need for a callback.

```
$(child).appendTo(parent)
        .focus();
```

If you are using multiple `append()` statements, this is actually considerably slower than simply appending something big once. That may explain why you are finding it is taking awhile in IE.

Comment: If this is ok, $(child).appendTo(parent); $(child).focus(); must work also. As I know, synchronous means commands are executed line by line.

Answer (score 0):

```
var oldHtml, el, toBeAppended;
function appendAndFocus()
{
   oldHtml = el.html();
   el.append(toBeAppended);
   appnedAndFocus_h()
}
function appnedAndFocus_h()
{
   if(el.html()==oldHtml) //if(el==oldHtml) - CORRECTED.
   {
      setTimeout(appendAndFocus_h, 10); //just for browser to be taken a breath.
      return;
   }
   else
   {
      el.focus();
   } 
}
```

**Notice** : Not tested code.

Comment: I believe the OP asked for an answer that doesn't use `setTimeout`

Comment: I understand and I leave a comment why I write setTimeout there.

Comment: I have tried with setTimeout but sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. That's why I want to know if there is any any way to work this out.

Comment: You use a exact time may be 3 or may be 5 seconds, the code which I wrote will try while element is not added.

Comment: @Enes Unal so what you have above does work but what i notice is sometimes if my machine is slow and the browser takes some time to load the statement does not work because it sleeps for 10ms and by then the append has not finished so the focus doesn't work. Is there any full proof way of making sure that the focus is always made after the append has finished? Thanks!

Comment: Man, man.. I'm so sorry about that, I made a mistake, `if(el==oldHtml)` should be `if(el.html()==oldHtml)` again and again, sorry.